# How do I use my Custom Logger in my notification service extension class? Adding the file to the extension's target membership does not work

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-app-extension, unnotificationserviceextension

I've added notification service extension to my project, and need to log something using my `CustomLogger.swift` class. Adding this class to the notification service's target membership (henceforth referred to as TM) simply does not work as it triggers a recursive stream of error. Anything class that is used in CustomLogger (that exists in the main project) is now required to be added to the extension's TM. This leads to a situation where almost every file in the project will have to be added to the extension's TM, rendering this infeasible.

I also tried simply importing the main app into the NotificationService class. However, this again triggers a stream of errors "Missing required module xyz", where xyz is any framework/library that the main project depends on. I add these to the "Embedded frameworks" in the extension, however, again this is infeasible as i would have to add all the frameworks that the main project depends on.

Any help is appreciated.